# htaccess rule for remove begining part of the url

Tags: .htaccess

I need to hide beginning part of the url. For example 
Url will be http://bookoffers.com?id=http://www.google.com
Where id will be another url. So I want to show only the value of the id. And hide "http://bookoffers.com?id=" this much part.

Comment: So you want the browser so display `http://www.google.com/` while it's actually going to a site called `http://bookoffers.com`?

Comment: Actually there are 3 sites. site1.com , site2.com, site3.com there are some links on site1.com which are going on site3.com or any other site. But I want those links will be first redirect to site2.com and then it will be automatically redirect to site3.com or any other site which will be in id parameter. So that site3.com will assume that this user is comes from site2.com not from site1.com. So I have made this type of url. and its working. but now i want to hide middle site from url.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this rule on top of other rules:

RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+\?id=(https?://[^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Did you place this as first rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`?